# How do I use Regex to match every occurrence of a string between two surrounding strings exclusive of the surrounding strings?

Tags: regex, grep

I'm struggling with regex. Here's the command I'm using (running Cygwin on Windows) upon hwnd’s suggestion (which had solved my previous issue):

```
grep -Po '(?<="id":)[^,]+' regex_test.txt
```

How can I change the regular expression so that the match created starts with **,{"id":** OR **:[{"id":** ? Sadly, the current expression is also capturing unwanted ID’s that are prepended with **:{"id":**

Input Text File named "regex_test.txt":

> reason":{"id":25549177,“pattern":null},"iphone":[{"id":2411977008,version":null},{"id":2430057923,

Output:

> 25549177
>
> 2411977008
>
> 2430057923

Desired Output:

> 2411977008
>
> 2430057923

Please let me know your thoughts on these issues.

Comment: @Сухой27 This question seem not to be a duplicate: It's about [pcre] and [grep] ! (shell use, not perl.) as I understand. Also `lookaround` is an interesting feature not shown in purposed link to pretended duplicata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **Positive Lookbehind** assertion ( *as shown in the linked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/192894/2206004)* ):

```
grep -Po '(?<="id":)[^,]+' regex_test.txt
```

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/HqLZ9j)

Comment: or `grep -Po '"id":\K[^,]+' regex_test.txt`

Comment: or `perl -nE 'say $& if /"id":\K[^,]+/' regex_test.txt`

Comment: @hwnd There are further issues I’m running into. How can I change your regular expression so that the match created starts with **,{"id":** OR **:[{"id":** (a more specific condition than the current **“id”:** ? Sadly, the current expression is also capturing unwanted ID’s that are prepended with **:{"id":** .

Comment: @Sonia, try `(?<=[[,]{"id":)[^,]+`

Comment: @hwnd That did the trick. I was trying to escape the [ { characters. Thank you!